# How to write a footnote attached to the author in a LaTeX paper?

Tags: footnotes, titles, amsart

I want to attach a footnote to each author of a paper and write that their research was supported by different grants. How do I do that? Simply `\footnote` after each author does not work.

Comment: I think we should either remove the {amsart} tag, since the question doesn't refer do this documentclass, or edit the question to include it. I'd vote for the former, to keep the question interesting for a broader audience, as the answer for `article` is already provided.

Comment: If you use `\thanks` for email addresses and want to reuse a domain e.g. `{foo,bar,me}@some-domain.edu` see at the answer from @Habi.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If your document class is `amsart` then the syntax is a bit different

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\title{My great paper}

\author{Fist author}
\thanks{The first author wants to thank someone.}

\author{Second author}
\thanks{The second author wants to thank someone else.}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Note that in the `\thanks` command you have to explicitly mention which information corresponds to which author, since no footnote “marks” will be printed with the acknowledgements. This is apparently the preferred style for AMS as discussed for example at the [The AMS article document class](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-68852-7_11).

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I will do, mention explicitly the information for each author.

Comment: At the end of the auteor add {\footnote{name of the first author}

Answer (score 34):

I think the command you're looking for is `\thanks`

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{My great paper}
\author{One author\thanks{some info} \and Another author\thanks{more info}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Still does not write Author^1, Author^2 etc and the corresponding text on the bottom of the page.

 It just writes all the "texts" at the bottom of the first page.

Comment: hmm, which document class are you using? the example code I posted (using `article`) works fine and produces something like Author1^* with a “*” footnote at the bottom

Comment: I'm using \documentclass[11pt]{amsart} with
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{diagrams}

Comment: I've added a second answer for the case of `amsart`.

Comment: Does `\thanks` support assigning the same affiliation to multiple authors? (I'm looking for vanilla latex solution, as the antiquated journal upload system does not even let me upload additional class files)

Comment: which document class are you using? the standard classes do not even have the concept of affiliation or institution. If you are using a non-standard class you might find it more helpful to ask a new question.

Comment: Should you not be using `\and` rather than commas to separate the authors?

Answer (score 5):

I've been doing something similar to have different authors with the same affiliation and have adapted an example from [Anthony Liekens](http://anthony.liekens.net/index.php/LaTeX/MultipleFootnoteReferences).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\footremember}[2]{%
   \footnote{#2}
    \newcounter{#1}
    \setcounter{#1}{\value{footnote}}%
}
\newcommand{\footrecall}[1]{%
    \footnotemark[\value{#1}]%
} 
\title{How to bowl properly}
\author{%
    The Dude\footremember{alley}{Holly Star Lanes Bowling Alley}%
    \and Walter Sobchak\footremember{trailer}{probably in a trailer park}%
    \and Jesus Quintana\footrecall{alley} \footnote{Mexico?}%
    \and Uli Kunkel\footrecall{trailer} \footnote{Germany?}%
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
The whole example is taken from \href{http://anthony.liekens.net/index.php/LaTeX/MultipleFootnoteReferences}{anthony liekens}\ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: however, this method doesn't allow for more than two footnotes with the same affiliation.

Comment: hey, sorry for not replying such a long time. i'm currently writing an abstract with three persons from our lab and two persons from another. we all share the same affiliation and this tip works fine, there are three persons with the same affiliation in my document...

Comment: @Suresh: Why? One could simply recall as often as I want to, or am I wrong?

Comment: Hello @Habi , maybe you could take a look at this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674003/declare-footnote-text-before-usage-in-the-preamble . Thanks in advance!