# Multiple \thanks that refer to same text

Tags: footnotes, affiliation

I'd like to have three authors that use the same footnote for their \thanks identifier (they are at the same university, and don't need separate affiliation notes). I've read one of the solutions proposed in [How to write a footnnote attached to the author in a LaTeX paper?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/how-to-write-a-footnnote-attached-to-the-author-in-a-latex-paper), but the last solution (using recalled footnotes) only works for **two** authors.

So an example: I'd like to have

> Author1* and Author2* and Author3*
>
> ---
>
> - University of Podunk, Timbuktoo.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

How about the following?

```
\newcommand*\samethanks[1][\value{footnote}]{\footnotemark[#1]}
\author{Foo\thanks{University of Podunk, Timbuktoo}
\and Bar\samethanks
\and Baz\thanks{Somewhere Else}
\and Bof\samethanks[1]
\and Hmm\samethanks}
```

The `\samethanks` either duplicate the previous value or if you give it the optional argument, it uses that value. So Foo, Bar, and Bof have the same affiliation. Baz and Hmm have the same affiliation, different from Foo, Bar, and Bof's.

Comment: Probably not so important, as author lists tend not to change for a paper. But it may be better to also redefine `\thanks` to take an optional argument which sets a counter `thanks@#1` to the value of footnote, and recall that mark in `\samethanks` rather than passing in the value of `footnote` by hand.

Comment: @Willie Wong: I'm not sure I follow. Why is it a better solution to have two identical counters?

Comment: They are not identical. My point was that I don't like the hard-coding of `Bof\samethanks[1]`. I would much prefer if you can say `Foo\thanks[foo]{..}` and then refer to it with `Bof\samethanks[foo]` which will be less of a hassle if you ever need to re-order the authors. I was not completely sure how `\thanks` work (is it really just a footnote environment?), so I wasn't sure if you can just `\label` it. Is this clearer now?

Comment: @Willie Wong: I see now. `\thanks` uses `\footnotemark` and then defines `\@thanks` as `\@thanks\footnotemark \protect\footnotetext[\the\c@footnote]{#1}}` I guess you could probably use `\label` and `\ref`, but it hardlyl seem worth it.

Comment: @WillieWong While I accepted the solution above, I'm interested in knowing how to do what you suggest. I'm not a good tex hacker

Answer (score 25):

I ran into this problem often in the past and my solution is like this

```
\author{Author1\thanks{University of Podunk, Timbuktoo.} \and 
  Author2\footnotemark[1] \and Author3\footnotemark[1]}
```

Not really flexible as one has to count but this is the easiest way I know.