# Using \author and \thanks for authors with common affiliations

Tags: footnotes, titles

What is the correct way to use `\author` and `\thanks` when I want to have multiple authors having common affiliations? For instance, using

```
\author{ABC\thanks{XYZ} \and DEF\thanks{UVW} \and GHI\thanks{XYZ}}
```

produces the following output

[image]

at the top of the page and the following output at the bottom of the page

[image]

I would like to get rid of `XYZ` repeating twice at the bottom of the page since authors `ABC` and `GHI` have same affiliation.

Comment: Take a look at this solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4171/171009

Answer (score 78, accepted):

There may be more general ways of dealing with this, but I'm not sure how much investment should be put in with greater reward than a quick manual intervention.

Since `\thanks` is just a footnote with a differently formatted number, you can use `\footnotemark[<num>]` to fix it to affiliation `<num>`. So, using your example, `GHI` belongs to `\footnotemark[1]`, which is the same as the affiliation of `ABC`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{My title}
\author{ABC\thanks{XYZ} \and DEF\thanks{UVW} \and GHI\footnotemark[1]}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}​
```

There's no need to provide an accompanying `\footnotetext`, since this is already provided by `\thanks{XYZ}` for `ABC`.

This minimal usage might not be optimal for accurate interaction with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). However, this might not be needed.

Comment: +1. Thanks! That really helped and I have it working fine now. The same works for adding multiple thanks as well using `\footnotemark[1] \footnotemark[2]` etc. I will wait for a few minutes before accepting an answer.

Comment: How to do the same using `amsart` class?

Comment: @Thiago: I would suggest asking a [follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/5764) since the solution might entail more than can be commented on. Please post it as a fresh one using the "[Ask Question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" link. Please also include a link to this question to provide the background.