# multiple footnotes using footmisc within author/thanks context

Tags: footnotes, titles, footmisc

I'm working on a paper with a large list of authors, hence I've switched to numeric author indices as illustrated at http://www.latex-community.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1517&view=next . Now I want to make sure that multiple affiliations for a single author are properly set off by commas, which should most obviously be handled by `\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}`.  Unfortunately, as shown below, this seems (?) to fail in the `\author` context (i.e., although other footnotes in the test document look OK, the ones in the author list are squished together)?  (I was originally using `\thanks` for the affiliations but tried switching in this example to `\footnote` -- I don't have any footnotes in the paper so I don't care about using a separate counter ...)

(In my real example I've also got affiliations shared by multiple authors as in [Using \author and \thanks for authors with common affiliations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61303/using-author-and-thanks) ; I generate the appropriate `\footnotemark` references using some R code ...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrtime}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@fnsymbol[1]{\the#1}  %% change footnotes to numeric superscripts
\makeatother
\author{Joe Schmo\footnote{first address}\footnote{second address} 
   \and Fred Blow \footnote{third address}\footnote{fourth address}}
\title{Test}
\date{\today @ \thistime}
\textheight=8cm
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Also try some footnotes: this\footnote{yes} and that\footnote{no}\footnote{maybe}
\end{document}
```

And the (disappointing) results (cropped with `pdfcrop`: a bit fuzzy, but I think it's clear even from this that the footnotes within the text are properly delimited while ones from within `\author{}` are not ...):

[first question I've posted on tex.stackexchange.com : feel free to suggest improvements to the question / critical information I left out ...]

[image]

Comment: You may want to check out this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62091/5001

Comment: @Mico , I will take a look -- thanks -- but my first reaction is that it doesn't seem to apply, since at least the main subject of the question is about incompatibility with the `hyperref` package, which I'm not using here ... **edit**: doesn't seem to help in this case (I think the problem may be with something `\author{}` does ??)

Comment: A tip for your MWE: Add `\textheight=8cm` (or some other size) to your preamble to make everything more compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `\maketitle` redefines `\@makefnmark`:

```
\def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
```

You can undo this using [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\patchcmd`:

```
\patchcmd\maketitle{%
  \def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}}{}{}{}
```

So my complete solution would be as follows (also using [`fnpct`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fnpct) instead of `footmisc` for once because I like it and second because it allows using `\thanks`, too):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrtime}
% fnpct instead of footmisc:
\usepackage[dont-mess-around]{fnpct}

% patch \maketitle:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% undo counter resetting in case there are more footnotes:
\patchcmd\maketitle{\setcounter{footnote}{0}}{}{}{}
% undo \@fnsymbol, add adapting of \thanks:
\patchcmd\maketitle{%
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}}{\AdaptNote\thanks\multthanks}{}{}
% undo redefinition of \@makefnmark:
\patchcmd\maketitle{%
  \def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}}{}{}{}
\makeatother

% both \footnote and \thanks work:
\author{Joe Schmo\footnote{first address}\footnote{second address} 
  \and Fred Blow\thanks{third address}\thanks{fourth address}}
\title{Test}
\date{\today\ @ \thistime}
\textheight=8cm

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Also try some footnotes: this\footnote{yes} and that\footnote{no}\footnote{maybe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

#### Update 2021, v1.0 of `fnpct`

The code below goves the same output as before.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrtime}
\usepackage{fnpct}

% patch \maketitle:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% undo counter resetting in case there are more footnotes:
\patchcmd\maketitle
  {\setcounter{footnote}{0}}
  {}{}{}

% undo \@fnsymbol:
\patchcmd\maketitle
  {\renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}}
  {}{}{}

% % undo redefinition of \@makefnmark:
\AdaptNote\thanks{+m}{\let\rlap\@firstofone #NOTE{#1}}
\makeatother

% both \footnote and \thanks work:
\author{Joe Schmo\footnote{first address}\footnote{second address} 
  \and Fred Blow\thanks{third address}\thanks{fourth address}}
\title{Test}
\date{\today\ @ \thistime}
\textheight=8cm

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Also try some footnotes: this\footnote{yes} and that\footnote{no}\footnote{maybe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: hmm.  having some trouble getting this to work, possibly/probably because my texlive installation is out of date (I'm on Ubuntu 10.04) ... will keep struggling ...