# Footnote on document author with footmisc

Tags: footnotes, titles, footmisc

I'm using the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[bottom,flushmargin,hang,multiple]{footmisc}
\title{Title}
\author{Joe Blow\footnote{Address}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Hello.\footnote{This is a footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the `flushmargin` option does not affect the footnote on the author. I would imagine there is a solution similar to the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75494/multiple-footnotes-using-footmisc-within-author-thanks-context), but I do not know the coding well enough to adapt it or come up with something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work, at least if the footnote to the author is short.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[bottom,flushmargin,hang,multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\maketitle{\hb@xt@1.8em}{\hbox}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\title{Title}
\author{Joe Blow\footnote{Address}}

\maketitle

Hello.\footnote{This is a footnote.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great indeed! There's a problem when using the `footnotebackref` package as well. Add it right below the `\makeatother`. For its functionality to be visible, you might want to add `\newpage\null` right above `\end document` as well. Then you see the author footnote is not getting the `footnotebackref` functionality.