# Things written in \thanks are indented. I don't want that

Tags: indentation, footnotes, titles

When I insert footnotes in my text, the first line of them is indented, which looks ugly. To prevent indentation I use

```
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
```

When I use `\thanks{...}` (to add information concerning an author) the `...` is indented - as the footnotes previously were. How to I prevent the indentation of the content from `\thanks` ?

Comment: This seems to be the same as [Footnote on document author with footmisc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113032/), since `\thanks` and `\footnote` are equivalent when in the argument to `\author`. If this helps, please let us know; otherwise, please add some information about the problems.

Comment: @egreg That link worked! Thanks! (I guess the question can be closed now.)