# equal contribution using thanks with llncs class

Tags: footnotes, lncs

I am trying to add equal contribution footnote using the \thanks keyword.

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\title{Some Title}

\author{Author1 \thanks{equal contribution} \and Author2 \footnotemark[1] \and Author3}
\institute{\email{email1, email2, email3} \\ Institute}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

This gives me an error,

> ! Use of \@xfootnotenext does not match its
>   definition

Any work around ?.

Comment: The error is caused by `\footnotemark`, not by `\thanks`

Comment: @egreg, I used footnotemark as a work around to get a single footnote for both authors (found in this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61303/using-author-and-thanks-for-authors-with-common-affiliations).  Is there any work around to get one foot note for both authors ?

Comment: That's not how `llncs` works, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that `\footnotemark` cannot be used in the `\author` field for `llncs`. Here's a workaround:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printfnsymbol}[1]{%
  \textsuperscript{\@fnsymbol{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Some Title}

\author{Author1\thanks{equal contribution}
\and Author2\printfnsymbol{1} \and Author3}
\institute{\email{email1, email2, email3} \\ Institute}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```