# How to add equal Equal contribution (co-first authors)?

Tags: author, sv-classes

How to add equal Equal contribution (co-first authors)?

Here the first author and second author are co-first authors. How to reflect that in latex?

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
\begin{document}

\title{Insert your title here%\thanks{Grants or other notes
%about the article that should go on the front page should be
%placed here. General acknowledgments should be placed at the end of the article.}
}
\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so, write it here}

%\titlerunning{Short form of title}        % if too long for running head

\author{First Author         \and
        Second Author \and
        Third Author
}

%\authorrunning{Short form of author list} % if too long for running head

\institute{F. Author \at
              first address \\
              \email{fauthor@example.com}
           \and
           S. Author \at
              \email{sauthor@example.com}
           \and
           T. Author \at
              \email{tauthor@example.com}
}

\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
% The correct dates will be entered by the editor


\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Insert your abstract here. Include keywords, PACS and mathematical
subject classification numbers as needed.
\keywords{First keyword \and Second keyword \and More}
% \PACS{PACS code1 \and PACS code2 \and more}
% \subclass{MSC code1 \and MSC code2 \and more}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
Your text comes here. Separate text sections with
\section{Section title}
\label{sec:1}

\subsection{Subsection title}
\label{sec:2}
as required. Don't forget to give each section
and subsection a unique label (see Sect.~\ref{sec:1}).



\end{document}
% end of file template.tex
```

I have to show the equal contribution of the first two authors in the following format:

[image]

I was able to do the following:

```
\author{Author 1$^*$}
\author{Author 2$^*$}
\author{Author 3}
```

And then:

```
\maketitle
\def\thefootnote{*}\footnotetext{These authors contributed equally to this work}\def\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}
```

The the formatting does not appear like the intended screenshot.

Comment: You can try using the `\thanks{...}` command inside the title for this. It does not look like `svjour3` has a default method to show equal contributions.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting for noting equal contribution varies by journal and LaTeX document class. For example, in `autart`, which is similar to `svjour3`, it is recommended to add a `thanksref` element after the author name:

```
\author{The Amplitwist\thanksref{equalAuth}},
\author{George P. Burdell\thanksref{equalAuth}}
\thanks[equalAuth]{Authors George P. Burdell and The Amplitwist contributed equally to this work.}
```

Check out [Using \author and \thanks for authors with common affiliations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61303/using-author-and-thanks-for-authors-with-common-affiliations) for more.