# Declare footnote text before usage in the preamble

Tags: columns, preamble

I want to reuse footnotes. The problem is that it is inside `\authors`, and some solutions won't work.

I tried first the [fixfoot](https://ctan.org/pkg/fixfoot) package, but it gives an [error](https://github.com/rf-latex/fixfoot/issues/2), and the package is not being updated for 4 years now.

This [fantastic answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1807/13364) I found here at TeX Stackexchange works just fine, but I'm interested in understanding and creating a simple tweak.

**1st: how it is working**

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\setfoot}[2]{%
    \footnote{#2}%
    \newcounter{#1}%
    \setcounter{#1}{\value{footnote}}%
}

\newcommand{\getfoot}[1]{%
    \footnotemark[\value{#1}]%
}

\title{Comparing two solutions}

\author{Last1, A.\setfoot{unia}{University of Pedramburguer}\\ a1@some.dd\and
Last2, B.\getfoot{unia}\\ email1@some.dd \and
Last3, C.\getfoot{unia}\\ email3@some.dd \and
Last4, D.\setfoot{unib}{University of Martalface}\\ email4@some.dd}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

body...

\end{document}
```

[image: Current Solution]

**2nd: how I would like it to work**

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\setfoot}[2]{%
    \footnote{#2}% <<<<<<<<<<<< error when you
    \newcounter{#1}%
    \setcounter{#1}{\value{footnote}}%
}

\newcommand{\getfoot}[1]{%
    \footnotemark[\value{#1}]%
}

\title{Comparing two solutions}

\setfoot{unia}{University of Pedramburguer} %<<<<<<<<<<< try to set it out
\setfoot{unib}{University of Martalface}    %<<<<<<<<<<< of begin document

\author{Last1, A.\getfoot{unia}\\ a1@some.dd\and
Last2, B.\getfoot{unia}\\ email1@some.dd \and
Last3, C.\getfoot{unia}\\ email3@some.dd \and
Last4, D.\getfoot{unib}\\ email4@some.dd}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

body...

\end{document}
```

So, to be able to set the foot with command `\setfoot` out of the `\begin{document}` it is necessary some TeX magic. Any help on this specific example? Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Habi https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/828/habi , maybe you can take a look ? Thanks

Comment: you can not call \footnote in the preamble.  You can only store the bare texts there.

Comment: That is clear to me, but how to do that would be greatly appreciated if you could show.

Comment: OTOH, author doesn't execute until \maketitle.  It just defines \@author.

Comment: Exactly. Chicken and egg situation.

Answer (score 1):

This is closer to what your want.  Note that `\maketitle` resets the footnote counter and changes the definition of `\thefootnote` to use asterisk etc.  Also, author is formatted inside an environment, and you can't put footnotes inside any environment.  Instead, it stores `\footnotetext` in a global macro `\@thanks` for later expansion.

A misspelled label in `\getfoot` will produce a `?`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Comparing two solutions}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setfoot}[2]{% #1=label, #2=footnote text
  \stepcounter{footnote}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname fn@#1\endcsname{\thefootnote}% create global macro
  \protected@xdef\@thanks{\@thanks
    \protect\footnotetext[\the\c@footnote]{#2}}%
  \ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\getfoot}[1]% #1=label
  {\@ifundefined{fn@#1}{?}{\textsuperscript{\csname fn@#1\endcsname}}}
\makeatother

\author{\setfoot{unia}{University of Pedramburguer}
        \setfoot{unib}{University of Martalface}
Last1, A.\getfoot{unia}\\ a1@some.dd\and
Last2, B.\getfoot{unia}\\ email1@some.dd \and
Last3, C.\getfoot{unia}\\ email3@some.dd \and
Last4, D.\getfoot{unib}\\ email4@some.dd}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

body...

\end{document}
```